# can LIKE with trailing % make use of an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;

CREATE TABLE t(
    mypath varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a'),('a/b'),('a/b/c');
```

-- Listing all parent paths using LIKE:

```
SELECT a.mypath, b.mypath aS parent_path
FROM t a
JOIN t b ON a.mypath LIKE b.mypath + '%' AND a.mypath != b.mypath
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but definitely not on such a small amount of data.

Comment: It's a **leading** wildcard that makes a query non-SARGable. A trailing one won't disable index use.

Comment: Suggestion - run the explain plan and see for yourself.

Comment: Forgot to mention, dataset is actually 6 million lines

Comment: This mask would utilise both conditions in one: `a.mypath like b.mypath + '_%'`

Comment: So everybody seems to agree it can use an index, thx

Comment: Have you tested it on your table with 6 Million rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can make use of an index, if it has a trailing wildcard.